# SwapExactTokensForTokens returns too many arguments

Tags: blockchain, uniswap

I'm making a automation for my farms and am using Netswap (Metis Andromeda Chain) to swap my yield into some other token. In this example I'm swapping Metis into USDC.

When I'm using swapExactTokensForTokens it returns, that I'm passing too many argumetns (count=5; expectedCount=4). According to their source code and my experience there should be 5 parameters.

When I'm using swapExactMetisForTokens (same es swapExactETHForTokens) it always returns "on-payable method cannot override value".

What am I missing or doing wrong? Code has been working fine on Fantom Opera...

Here's my call:

```
if(ethers.utils.formatEther(wmetisBalance.toString()) > 0.5){
    var time = new Date().getDate();
    if (time % 2 != 0) {
        yieldToken = tusdcToken;
        console.log("usdc token");
    } else  {
        yieldToken = tusdcToken;
        console.log("eth token");
    }
    const swappingTX = await signedSwapping.swapExactTokensForTokens(wmetisBalance.sub(100000000000000000n), 0, [metisToken, yieldToken], process.env.adminAddress, deadline);
    console.log(`swapTX: ${swappingTX.hash}`);
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 10000));
} else {
    console.log("too low metis to trade");
}
```

and this is what I'll get

```
  reason: 'too many arguments: passed to contract',
  code: 'UNEXPECTED_ARGUMENT',
  count: 5,
  expectedCount: 4
```

My call directly with swapExactETHForTokens looks like this:

```
   const swappingTX = await signedSwapping.swapExactETHForTokens(0, [metisToken, yieldToken], process.env.adminAddress, deadline,     {
        value: wmetisBalance.sub(100000000000000000n),
        gasPrice: 17000000000,
        gasLimit: 196271
    });
```

Maybe someone has any idea or give me a hint what I'm missing.

Comment: Check your ABI. Probably it has the method's arguments incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

If you're swapping a token from ETH to another token, make sure to pass the ETH value like so in the Smart Contract:

```
        uniswap.swapExactETHForTokens{value: msg.value}(
            amountOut,
            path,
            msg.sender,
            deadline
        );
```

Meaning use `{value: msg.value}` if you're using a modern solidity version.

Also you have to use `swapExactETHForTokens` for swapping ETH to another token. Don't use `swapExactTokensForTokens` for swapping ETH to a token.